# Delete the last character when a key is pressed on a textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, keypress

I'm trying to block the user press the same key (by example if the user have "asd" in a `TextBox` and the user press "x" the text box still contains "asd" but don't insert "x"), I have tried using `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` but it delete the last character but insterts the pressed ("asx" it deletes "d"). Sorry for my bad english.

```
private void txtInsert_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 104) //I'm trying to delete "h"
        {
            string cadena = txtInsert.Text;
            cadena = cadena.Substring(0, cadena.Length - 1);
            txtInsert.Text = cadena;
            string cadena = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < txtInsert.TextLength-1; i++)
            {
                cadena += txtInsert.Text[i];
            }
            txtInsert.Text = "";
            txtInsert.Text = cadena;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us your code so we can understand better what is going on.

Comment: Done @RahulSharma, i hope yours can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `KeyPress` event (so we have `char` to operate with, not *key* which can be, say, *left shift*) and `Handled` in order to prevent user input (WinForms example):

```
private void myTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  TextBox box = sender as TextBox;

  // Do nothing if 
  e.Handled = 
    e.KeyChar >= ' ' &&    // key is not control one (e.g. not backspace)
    box.Text.Length >= 3;  // Text Box Text has Length >= 3
}
```

If you want to prevent adding `'h'`

```
  // Do nothing on 'h' character
  e.Handled = e.KeyChar == 'h';
```